# What do I need to do to raise my "Speed" rating?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

In Tempest Trials, after winning a trial, you're shown a point calculation. It increases the number of levels you beat by certain multipliers. One of these is Speed. I almost always get an E rating which only gives me a 10% bonus. Once, I got a D rating, but I'm not sure how I did that, because I felt that I spent a lot of time setting up in that run.

What should I be trying to do in the Tempest Trials to increase my Speed rating?

Comment: According to [this](http://feheroes.gamepedia.com/Tempest_Trials#Scoring), your rating is determined by how many turns it takes to complete the trail, but it doesn't state how many turns correspond to each rating.

Comment: The only time I did not get an A, was in a battle where there were only two units left who took 6 damage per turn from each other, and both had renewal 3. I think that battle took like 28 turns or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by Arcane, "speed" in this context means the total number of turns it takes to complete all of the battles.  As noted on [the wiki](https://feheroes.gamepedia.com/Tempest_Trials#Scoring), the way to get an A is to beat all of the battles in 28 turns or less:

```
Speed Rank  Multiplier  Total Turns
    A          1.5x      Turns ≤ 28
    B          1.4x        29-31
    C          1.3x        32-35
    D          1.2x        36-39
    E          1.1x      Turns ≥ 40
```

This number does not appear to be affected by the number of maps, so it's much harder to get an A rank on the harder difficulties.  With only 3 maps, that's an average of ~9 turns/map, while with 7 maps you only get 4 turns/map.

A suggestion that may help in this category is to use units with more mobility and range.  Using cavalry units will help you get into position easier, and bow/dagger/magic users will be able to hit enemy units from a farther distance.  A team of armored units are unlikely to clear these battles efficiently enough to get an A for speed.

Note that each team you lose loses you 5% bonus from the survival category, which stacks multiplicatively.  An `A` for survival with an `E` rank for speed is 1.2*1.1 = 1.32 which is slightly worse than a `D` survival and `C` speed (1.05*1.3 = 1.365), so it'll be worth losing a few weaker teams for speed as long as you can at least get a `C`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to focus on completing your maps in the fewest turns possible to increase your speed. On average I complete most maps in 2-3 turns, 4-5 max. This gives me a consistent A rank for speed. Since the multipliers stack, don't worry to much about surviving and focus on quick wins. If your team dies and you have to use a second team as long as you kept up the speed and had a bonus ally you'll suffer only a small drop in your score